# Finding processor information in Ubuntu: Theoretical peak performance?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

I am interested in finding the theoretical peak performance in GFLops (both single and double precision) of my processor in Ubuntu 10.10. How do I find that?

The processor on my desktop machine is this one: [Intel Core I7 960](http://ark.intel.com/products/37151/Intel-Core-i7-960-Processor-%288M-Cache-3_20-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI%29)

Through the Linux terminal, I tried using `cat /proc/cpuinfo` but it does not seem to give that detail. Here is the output anyway if it helps:

```
processor       : 7
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 26
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 960  @ 3.20GHz
stepping        : 5
cpu MHz         : 1600.000
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 6415.90
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 1):

Look up the CPU model in /proc/cpuinfo, and then look up the CPU spec sheet from which you can calculate the theoretical FLOPS.

Comment: What is the formula for calculating Theoretical Peak performance?

Comment: @smilingbuddha: Number of flops/clock cycle/core * frequency * number of cores